# Can you explain this react function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

This is the function that fetches the products from the database for the products page of a eCommerce website.

I am trying to write a similar function for sign-in.

Can you help me with that I am new to react?

```
storedProducts = () => {
  axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/product')
    .then(res => {
      const storedProducts = res.data;
      let tempProducts = [];
      storedProducts.forEach(item => {
        const singleItem = { ...item
        };
        tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];

      });
      this.setState(() => {
        return {
          products: tempProducts
        };
      });
    })
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to understand?

Comment: Other than setting some component state this is javascript. Is there a more specific issue and/or question?

Comment: what is happening under storedProduct.forEach?

Comment: I think [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is causing the confusion

Comment: It's collecting all the storedProducts into an array. It's complete overkill since storedProducts is already an array. It's also making unnecessary copies of each item as well.

Comment: I dont get what exactly is happening in this code block.Can some please explain the code?

Comment: @AritraBhattacharyya which parts do you not understand? Cause one could explain everything including syntax and special characters, or just some methods…

Comment: It's basically doing `this.setState({ products: storedProducts });` with a lot of unnecessary shallow object copying (the spread syntax (`...`)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration the current item of the `storedProduct` is cloned into a new object (`singeItem`). In the next line this `singleItem` is appended to a new array that is reassigend to `tempProducts`. `tempProducts` is a complete new array object created using the spread operator.

Answer (score 2):

The code you pasted is an assignment of an anonymous arrow function to a variable `storedProducts`.

It seems to be cut from a class definition of a component. Components are the building blocks of React javascript library that allow building UI by building trees of these components, similar to HTML.

The only part that deals with anything related to React is this one:

```
this.setState(()=>{
  return {products:tempProducts};
});
```

It sets the state of the component, which normally causes the component to rerender – https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

```
const storedProducts = res.data;
let tempProducts = [];
storedProducts.forEach(item => {
  const singleItem = { ...item };
 tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
});
```

This whole block is quite strange, because seems unneeded. It takes an array `res.data` (I know it’s an array because `forEach` is used to iterate it in the following line, and that is an Array method) and iterates over items of it, creating copies using `spread` syntax `const singleItem = { ...item };` (literally, assign new object to singleItem and copy all properties of `item` into it). Since `res.data` is already an array, it could be used directly to set state of the component like this:

```
this.setState(()=>{
  return { products: res.data };
});
```